# Ruby on Rails console, beginner error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

In rails console when I want to add a column to my table with below command

```
  2.1.1 :001 >post = Post.new( :title => "first post", :job => "first job”)
```

it gives me

```
 2.1.1 :002">
 2.1.1 :003"> 
 2.1.1 :004">
```

and doing nothing! I don't know what is problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close quotes.

```
"first job”
```

Note that `”` are not the same as `"` Console is waiting for you to close all the brackets and quotes before it executes the command.

Answer (score 1):

if you copied and pasted the code the problem is with the last double-quotes

```
'”'.ord #=> 8221
'"'.ord #=> 34

'”' == '"' #=> false
```

Comment: Thanks I am too beginner.